# Issue with Photometric Interpretation tag even after inverting the image data

Tags: jpeg, tiff, libtiff.net

Note: Giving the background of my previous question once again so as to find all the related stuff at one source.

I'm capturing an image from an android mobile device and it’s in JPEG format. The image is of 72X72DPI and 24 bit. When I try to convert this JPEG image to TIFF using LibTiff.Net and to set the tag Photometric Interpretation = 0 for MinIsWhite, the image turns negative (the white becomes black and black becomes white). The environment is Windows 8.1 64 bit, Visual Studio 2012. The tag must have value 0, where 0 = white is zero.

I absolutely must use Photometric.MINISWHITE in images so tried inverting image data before writing it to TIFF as per the below code. But then the compression changes to LZW instead of CCITT4,Photometric is changed to MINISBLACK from MINISWHITE, FIllorder tag is removed, PlanarConfig tag is removed, New tag Predictor is added with value 1 and the image turns negative again.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_ASCIITAG = (TiffTag)666;
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_LONGTAG = (TiffTag)667;
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_SHORTTAG = (TiffTag)668;
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_RATIONALTAG = (TiffTag)669;
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_FLOATTAG = (TiffTag)670;
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_DOUBLETAG = (TiffTag)671;
        private const TiffTag TIFFTAG_BYTETAG = (TiffTag)672;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"D:\Projects\ITests\images\IMG_2.jpg"))
            {
                // convert jpg image to tiff
                byte[] tiffBytes = GetTiffImageBytes(bmp, false);
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\Projects\ITests\images\output.tif", tiffBytes);

                //Invert the tiff image
                Bitmap bmpTiff = new Bitmap(@"D:\Projects\ITests\images\output.tif");
                Bitmap FBitmap = Transform(bmpTiff);
                FBitmap.Save(@"D:\Projects\ITests\images\invOutput1.tif");

            }
        }

        public static byte[] GetTiffImageBytes(Bitmap img, bool byScanlines)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] raster = GetImageRasterBytes(img);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (Tiff tif = Tiff.ClientOpen("InMemory", "w", ms, new TiffStream()))
                    {
                        if (tif == null)
                            return null;

                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, img.Width);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, img.Height);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.CCITTFAX4);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISWHITE);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, img.Height);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION, 200);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION, 200);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE, 0);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 1);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.FILLORDER, FillOrder.LSB2MSB);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.ORIENTATION, BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.Orientation.TOPLEFT);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.RESOLUTIONUNIT, ResUnit.INCH);
                        tif.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, PlanarConfig.CONTIG);
                        int tiffStride = tif.ScanlineSize();
                        int stride = raster.Length / img.Height;
                        if (byScanlines)
                        {
                            // raster stride MAY be bigger than TIFF stride (due to padding in raster bits) 
                            for (int i = 0, offset = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
                            {
                                bool res = tif.WriteScanline(raster, offset, i, 0);
                                if (!res)
                                    return null;

                                offset += stride;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (tiffStride < stride)
                            {
                                // raster stride is bigger than TIFF stride 
                                // this is due to padding in raster bits 
                                // we need to create correct TIFF strip and write it into TIFF 
                                byte[] stripBits = new byte[tiffStride * img.Height];
                                for (int i = 0, rasterPos = 0, stripPos = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
                                {
                                    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(raster, rasterPos, stripBits, stripPos, tiffStride);
                                    rasterPos += stride;
                                    stripPos += tiffStride;
                                }

                                // Write the information to the file 
                                int n = tif.WriteEncodedStrip(0, stripBits, stripBits.Length);
                                if (n <= 0)
                                    return null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Write the information to the file 
                                int n = tif.WriteEncodedStrip(0, raster, raster.Length);
                                if (n <= 0)
                                    return null;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static byte[] GetImageRasterBytes(Bitmap img)
        {
            // Specify full image
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);

            Bitmap bmp = img;
            byte[] bits = null;

            try
            {
                // Lock the managed memory 
                if (img.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
                    bmp = convertToBitonal(img);

                BitmapData bmpdata = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

                // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
                bits = new byte[bmpdata.Stride * bmpdata.Height];

                // Copy the sample values into the array.
                Marshal.Copy(bmpdata.Scan0, bits, 0, bits.Length);

                // Release managed memory
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (bmp != img)
                    bmp.Dispose();
            }

            return bits;
        }

        private static Bitmap convertToBitonal(Bitmap original)
        {
            int sourceStride;
            byte[] sourceBuffer = extractBytes(original, out sourceStride);

            // Create destination bitmap
            Bitmap destination = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height,
                PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

            destination.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

            // Lock destination bitmap in memory
            BitmapData destinationData = destination.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height),
                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

            // Create buffer for destination bitmap bits 
            int imageSize = destinationData.Stride * destinationData.Height;
            byte[] destinationBuffer = new byte[imageSize];

            int sourceIndex = 0;
            int destinationIndex = 0;
            int pixelTotal = 0;
            byte destinationValue = 0;
            int pixelValue = 128;
            int height = destination.Height;
            int width = destination.Width;
            int threshold = 500;

            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                sourceIndex = y * sourceStride;
                destinationIndex = y * destinationData.Stride;
                destinationValue = 0;
                pixelValue = 128;

                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // Compute pixel brightness (i.e. total of Red, Green, and Blue values)
                    pixelTotal = sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 1] + sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 2] +
                        sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 3];

                    if (pixelTotal > threshold)
                        destinationValue += (byte)pixelValue;

                    if (pixelValue == 1)
                    {
                        destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
                        destinationIndex++;
                        destinationValue = 0;
                        pixelValue = 128;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pixelValue >>= 1;
                    }

                    sourceIndex += 4;
                }

                if (pixelValue != 128)
                    destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
            }

            Marshal.Copy(destinationBuffer, 0, destinationData.Scan0, imageSize);
            destination.UnlockBits(destinationData);
            return destination;
        }

        private static byte[] extractBytes(Bitmap original, out int stride)
        {
            Bitmap source = null;

            try
            {
                // If original bitmap is not already in 32 BPP, ARGB format, then convert 
                if (original.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                {
                    source = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    source.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(source))
                    {
                        g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    source = original;
                }

                // Lock source bitmap in memory
                BitmapData sourceData = source.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                // Copy image data to binary array 
                int imageSize = sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height;
                byte[] sourceBuffer = new byte[imageSize];
                Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, sourceBuffer, 0, imageSize);

                // Unlock source bitmap
                source.UnlockBits(sourceData);
                stride = sourceData.Stride;
                return sourceBuffer;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (source != original)
                    source.Dispose();
            }

        }

        public Bitmap Transform(Bitmap bitmapImage)
        {
            var bitmapRead = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            var bitmapLength = bitmapRead.Stride * bitmapRead.Height;
            var bitmapBGRA = new byte[bitmapLength];
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapRead.Scan0, bitmapBGRA, 0, bitmapLength);
            bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapRead);
            for (int i = 0; i < bitmapLength; i += 4)
            {
                bitmapBGRA[i] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i]);
                bitmapBGRA[i + 1] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i + 1]);
                bitmapBGRA[i + 2] = (byte)(255 - bitmapBGRA[i + 2]);
                //        [i + 3] = ALPHA.
            }

            var bitmapWrite = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmapImage.Width, bitmapImage.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapBGRA, 0, bitmapWrite.Scan0, bitmapLength);
            bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bitmapWrite);

            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invert image bytes in `GetTiffImageBytes` method, before writing them to TIFF. Also, the `Transform` method converts bi-level image to 32bpp one and that is why you get LZW compressed image in the end.

So, add the following code

```
for (int k = 0; k < raster.Length; k++)
    raster[k] = (byte)(~raster[k]);
```

after `byte[] raster = GetImageRasterBytes(img);` in `GetTiffImageBytes` method. This will invert image bytes. And don't use the following code

```
//Invert the tiff image
Bitmap bmpTiff = new Bitmap(@"D:\Projects\ITests\images\output.tif");
Bitmap FBitmap = Transform(bmpTiff);
FBitmap.Save(@"D:\Projects\ITests\images\invOutput1.tif");
```

Comment: You are my superstar, Bobrovsky! It worked exactly as required. Very thankful to you for your timely help. Cheers!